# get visual children that are not shown in the UI

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5

I have made a CheckedListBox control with the following DataTemplate:

```
<WrapPanel>
    <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox" VerticalAlignment="Center"
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" Margin="5,2" />
</WrapPanel>
```

I codebehind I need to get access to the CheckBox that belongs to a ListBoxItem:

```
foreach (var value in Items)
{
    var item = ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(value) as ListBoxItem;
    var checkBox = item?.GetVisualChildren<CheckBox>().FirstOrDefault();
}

public static IEnumerable<T> GetVisualChildren<T>(this DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                yield return (T)child;
            }

            foreach (T childOfChild in GetVisualChildren<T>(child))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when my Listbox has so many items that they can't all be shown without a scrollbar then `GetVisualChildren` returns null for the items that are outside the visible part. The same applies for all items if the control has not been rendered yet. How can I change this code to consistently get access to the CheckBox of a ListBoxItem regardless of the render state of the item? I have tried visual trees, logical trees, [FindName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and have not found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to change VirtualizingStackPanel that keeps only items that are visible, to simple StackPanel as ItemsPanel. If perfomance is not critical and there wouldn't be many items, this should help:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: well that was an easy solution!